# What is a renderer in cytoscape.js, and how do I write one?

Tags: cytoscape.js

What is the purpose of a renderer in cytoscape.js?
How can I write a custom renderer?

This is something not explained in detail in the [documentation](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/) (apart from one example)

Answer (score 0):

The renderer draws everything and reports user interaction to the core, as explained in the diagram in the docs.

You can find out more about renderers on Wikipedia: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics)

Unless you want to use a different rendering technology than canvas or you want to render the elements completely differently, there is not much point in writing your own renderer. It's a lot of work.

Comment: custom rendering would ease React Native interaction